# Open project from Visual Studio 2019 Developer Power Shell

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, command-line, visual-studio-2019

I have installed Visual Studio 2019 community version, but it is somehow in a conflict with Visual Studio Code. When I open the Developer PowerShell in Studio 2019, direct to a project folder and enter "code .", the projects gets opened in Visual Studio Code. How can I set-up Visual Studio 2019 as default program? I know how to do it for certain file-formats, but not for project folders as a whole.
Thanks!